# Creating a sidebar with an image next to it using only HTML

Tags: html, sidebar

I am trying to make a sidebar with links which I have done, but the image is sitting under the text.
I have centered the image but don't know how to align it to the right of the text.

```
   <div class="sidebar">
    <span style="vertical-align: middle;">
    <a href="#about"style="font-size: 100px;">Best Audio Quality</a></tr> <br>
    <a href="google.ca" style="font-size: 100px;">Budget Gaming</a> <br>
    <a href="#clients" style="font-size: 100px;">Top 10 of 2020</a> <br>
    <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 100px;">XBOX</a> <br>
    <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 100px;">PS4</a> <br>
    <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 100px;">PC</a> <br>
    <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 100px;">Nintendo Switch</a> <br>
    <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 100px;">Music</a> <br>

    <center>
        
        <div class="w3-content">
            <span style="vertical-align: middle;"></span>
          <img class="mySlides" src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/kbpt9fYfJbKbJ5WrHKRhrS-2560-80.jpg.webp" alt="custom_html_banner1" style="width:40%">
         
         </div>
         </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way would be to use align="right" `<p>text here<img src="myimage.jpg" align="right" /></p>`

Comment: would this still work with links a href instead of <p>
it doesnt seem to be working like this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to align your image to the right of the text, you can use `style=" float: right;"`. This will bring the image to the right border of the block element and the text to the left side. But you should put the image on top of the text you want to align.

If you just want the image to be on the right of the text using HTML only, you can just simply include the image right after your text contained by an inline element. The inline elements only take the place needed for the content inside it, so they will be basically in the same line. `<img>` is also an inline element. So this will do the trick.

`<span>Your <a> tags in here</span><img />`
or you can also apply `style="display: inline;"` to the container of the `<a>` tags.

Here is the list of [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified a bit and used [CSS Flexbox rules](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp) to give you some other ideas for how you may want to lay out your content in these cases. See a working example of the code below here @ http://www.cssdesk.com/vPeFm

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
     <div class="sidebar">
         <a href="#about" style="font-size: 20pt;">Best Audio Quality</a>
         <a href="google.ca" style="font-size: 20pt;">Budget Gaming</a>
         <a href="#clients" style="font-size: 20pt;">Top 10 of 2020</a>
         <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 20pt;">XBOX</a>
         <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 20pt;">PS4</a>
         <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 20pt;">PC</a>
         <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 20pt;">Nintendo Switch</a>
         <a href="#contact" style="font-size: 20pt;">Music</a>
     </div>
     <div class="w3-content">
         <img class="mySlides" 
              src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/kbpt9fYfJbKbJ5WrHKRhrS-2560-80.jpg.webp" 
              alt="custom_html_banner1" style="width:40%"
          />
     </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar {
  display : flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.w3-content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```